# PHP - dynamic link rewrite .HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am having a hard time with this. HTACCESS is something I hate and I am trying so much to get this right. I have a server running Linux and, I think, Debian. Well, that being so:

Some one please explain this to be since I am a newbie in this HTACCESS domain.

My Dynamic URL: `mydomain.com/index.php?Page=1&txtKeyword=`

I need to prettify this thus: `mydomain.com/index/Page/1/txtKeyword//`

My .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index/Page/(.*)/txtKeyword/(.*)/ index.php?Page=$1&txtKeyword=$2
RewriteRule index/Page/(.*)/txtKeyword/(.*) index.php?Page=$1&txtKeyword=$2
```

I did this and nothing is happening.

Is there anything I need to add in my PHP file as well? Or only adding the code above  to the .htaccess is enough(???) for my url rewrite???

If adding only in .htaccess and nothing to add in the php file, why isn't this working???

Appreciate your great help.

Comment: check your mod-rewrite in your server admin to know if its on

Comment: Hi, Yes the server party said its on! and how I came to know its on is, I disable backslash after index.php\ like this and it worked. So HTACCESS is working.

Comment: to know if its on go to the directory where you have the htaccess in your php file, print_r(phpinfo()); then search the array for mod-rewrite to know if its enabled

Comment: I have placed it in the root  the htaccess file where the index.php about php is....

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you may have [Multiviews](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews) turned on. In some setups, this is turned on by default because it helps with matching requests to the content. If you are *sure* you have mod_rewrite turned on and that you have the ability to use mod_rewrite in htaccess files (will need the `FileInfo` option I believe), then you can try turning OFF Multiviews.

With Multiviews on, apache will see a request like `/index/`, and see that there's a file named `index.php` and fuzzy map the request directly to `index.php`. And since this happens before mod_rewrite gets a chance to do its thing, this ends up bypassing the rule. At the top of your htaccess file, try adding:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Also note that the rule takes `mydomain.com/index/Page/1/txtKeyword/` and internally translates that to `mydomain.com/index.php?Page=1&txtKeyword=`. So it expects that all your links already look like `/index/Page/....` These rules will **NOT** magically change what's in your url address bar.

Comment: Dear Jon Lin thank you for the time taken. Thank you. Okay today I will try this code and get back. Can you also please tell me is there anything else I need to do in the PHP file or the HTACCESS code alone is enough for Dynamic url's to make the difference.